# How to move between modes using .vimrc?

Tags: vim, vi

I have a .vimrc script that automatically creates a buffer for a bash terminal with Conque (and goes to insert mode) and then returns to the previous buffer (the file I have opened).

```
autocmd VimEnter * ConqueTermSplit bash
autocmd VimEnter * wincmd p
```

The problem is that when I start vim I am left in insert mode and I have to press `<Esc>` every time to go to normal mode.

Writing `<C-v><Esc>` at the end of .vimrc doesn't work, as the command is executed in command mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have that plugin

<strike>autocmd VimEnter * exec "ConqueTermSplit bash" | silent norm!</strike>

could work

**Update** Just found out that Conque's documentation **[rocks](http://conque.googlecode.com/svn-history/r457/trunk/doc/conque_term.txt)**

You can use the `conque_term#open({command}, [buf_opts], [remain])` function to achieve what you want:

> If you ***don't want the new terminal buffer to become the new active buffer***, set
>    **`[remain]`** to 1. Only works if you create a split screen using **`[options]`**.

---

So what you'd want is roughly

```
 autocmd VimEnter * call conque_term#open('/bin/bash', ['split', 'resize 20'], 1)
```

Comment: silent exec does nothing I could see in my case

Comment: **Update**: have found the Conque plugin allows you to use an API to do what you want.

Comment: Nope! I see no difference again.

Comment: @DimitarSlavchev: try running `call conque_term#open('/bin/bash', ['split', 'resize 20'], 1)` directly in command mode and see whether it makes the shell window active? If so, file a bug at http://code.google.com/p/conque/issues/list

Comment: I am quite new to programming and I have no idea how that would work even in principle. Thanks for the help.

Comment: That solves it. Thanks. The only difference is that it now opens it above rather than bellow the main window, but I fixed it with
    set splitbelow